# Why does appending values mixed with empty cells to a csv using dlmwrite result in too few columns?

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm using Matlab 2012a to append a <1x19 cell> to a CSV file using dlmwrite.  The cell array includes 17 numbers and 2 blanks. The result: 17 values written to the target csv file, but the two blanks missing. I am using the codes below:

```
    Output=num2cell([var1,var2,var3....var19]);
    Output(cellfun(@isnan,Output)) = {[]};
    dlmwrite('Target.csv',Output_m,'-append');
```

When I run the codes in command window I can see the blanks appear in the Output:

```
    Output = 

    Columns 1 through 10

    [19]    [2]    [137.5994]    [0]    []    [501.3610]    [38.4230]    [0]    [0]    [4.9160]

    Columns 11 through 19

    [4.9160]    [38.4230]    [0]    [38.4230]    [501.6580]    []    [-1.2590]    [0]    [0]
```

But when appended to the csv file, the blanks disappear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is laid out in the documentation:

> dlmwrite(filename,M) writes **numeric data** in array M to an ASCII format file, filename, using the default delimiter (,) to separate array elements. If the file, filename, already exists, dlmwrite overwrites the file.

Non-numeric data is ignored, which is why the data is lost.

One way of resolving the issue is to write a number like `-Inf` and then use a post-processor to remove those elements